# Jquery file upload not working in ie9

Tags: jquery, file-upload, ember.js, jquery-plugins, ember-cli

I referenced all necessary scripts

```
app.import('vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js');    
app.import('vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js');
app.import('vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js');
```

but from ie9 request files is empty, ie9 doesn't support file-upload XHR requests but uploader should use iframe-transport for this browser. what request from ie9 looks like:

```
Client
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.7,ka;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

why it is still XMLHttpRequest in ie? It works fine in chrome and ie10+

Comment: what is `app` exactly?

Comment: this is ember code, and just reference scripts in vendor.js file

Comment: I have found out some answers about inserting additional scripts for ie9 (xdr-transport.js) , to follow the documentation it is not needed @Alex